# Как восстановить пароль modx?

Tags: php, modx

Сайт на modx. Надо восстановить админский пароль. Все доступы есть. Восстановление через почту не выходит - не приходят письма. Пытался в базе поменять как в [этой статье](https://cat-art.ru/blog/razblokirovat-polzovatelya-sbrosit-parol-modx-phpmyadmin), но все равно пишет что пароль неверный.

Comment: Вы удалили вопрос. Я подготовил ответ про fileList

Comment: @AzizUmarov я уже решил проблему по другому, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Если доступы есть, киньте в корень сайта следующий файлик, поправьте путь и по необходимости учетные данные и запустите.
https://gist.github.com/himurovich/b2feb36ff680d6ea1d7c4a0e9b78e61f
Это обновит существующего пользователя с нужными правами, должно помочь.
Иначе возможно что-то поломалось(

Comment: Кажется я понял. В логах пишет: `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2005] Unknown MySQL server host '127.0.0.1:3310'`. Но что странно я перепроверил настройки подключения - все 100% правильно! Не понимаю как так может быть...

Comment: Любопытно, т.е. все остальное работает? и сайт и админка? только пароль нельзя восстановить? А удалите-ка кеш /core/cache/, что после увидите?

Comment: Да уже пробовал. После удаления кэша сайт перестал работать. Походу закэшировался. Но почему не может подключиться хз...

Comment: Так и есть - кеш вам отображался. Проблема - исключительно в подключении к базе. на всякий случай(да, перепроверили, но знаете как бывает..)
$database_server = '127.0.0.1:3306';
$database_dsn = 'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306;dbname=instance_name;charset=utf8';
синтаксис, адреса портов...вплоть до запятой и точки запятой, все верно? Сам-то mysql запущен? Если MODX конфиги не правили особо, то по опыту могу сказать, что надо настройки базы смотреть..может firewall, что-то еще.. MODX обычно четко цепляется, без проблем.

Comment: Может localhost вместо 127.0.0.1 поможет? :)